# How to make selecting random rows in Oracle faster with table with millions of rows?

Tags: oracle

Is there a way to make selecting random rows faster in Oracle with a table that has millions of rows? I tried to use sample(x) and dbms_random.value and it's taking a long time to run.

Comment: Please the sql you are executing.

Comment: Is there an index on the column that is being used to select the row?

Comment: @Janek: sample only works on full table scans.

Answer (score 10):

Using appropriate values of `sample(x)` is the fastest way you can.  It's block-random and row-random within blocks, so if you only want one random row:

```
select dbms_rowid.rowid_relative_fno(rowid) as fileno,
       dbms_rowid.rowid_block_number(rowid) as blockno,
       dbms_rowid.rowid_row_number(rowid) as offset
  from (select rowid from [my_big_table] sample (.01))
 where rownum = 1
```

I'm using a subpartitioned table, and I'm getting pretty good randomness even grabbing multiple rows:

```
select dbms_rowid.rowid_relative_fno(rowid) as fileno,
       dbms_rowid.rowid_block_number(rowid) as blockno,
       dbms_rowid.rowid_row_number(rowid) as offset
  from (select rowid from [my_big_table] sample (.01))
 where rownum <= 5

    FILENO    BLOCKNO     OFFSET
---------- ---------- ----------
       152    2454936         11
       152    2463140         32
       152    2335208          2
       152    2429207         23
       152    2746125         28
```

I suspect you should probably tune your `SAMPLE` clause to use an appropriate sample size for what you're fetching.

Answer (score 3):

Start with Adam's answer first, but if `SAMPLE` just isn't fast enough, even with the ROWNUM optimization, you can use block samples:

```
....FROM [table] SAMPLE BLOCK (0.01)
```

This applies the sampling at the block level instead of for each row. This does mean that it can skip large swathes of data from the table so the sample percent will be very rough. It's not unusual for a SAMPLE BLOCK with a low percentage to return zero rows.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the same question on AskTom:

http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:6075151195522

If you know how big your table is, use sample block as described above. If you don't, you can modify the routine below to get however many rows you want.

Copied from: http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:6075151195522#56174726207861

```
create or replace function get_random_rowid
( table_name varchar2
) return urowid
as
sql_v varchar2(100);
urowid_t dbms_sql.urowid_table;
cursor_v integer;
status_v integer;
rows_v integer;
begin
  for exp_v in -6..2 loop
    exit when (urowid_t.count > 0);
    if (exp_v < 2) then
      sql_v := 'select rowid from ' || table_name
      || ' sample block (' || power(10, exp_v) || ')';
    else
      sql_v := 'select rowid from ' || table_name;
    end if;
    cursor_v := dbms_sql.open_cursor;
    dbms_sql.parse(cursor_v, sql_v, dbms_sql.native);
    dbms_sql.define_array(cursor_v, 1, urowid_t, 100, 0);
    status_v := dbms_sql.execute(cursor_v);
    loop
      rows_v := dbms_sql.fetch_rows(cursor_v);
      dbms_sql.column_value(cursor_v, 1, urowid_t);
      exit when rows_v != 100;
    end loop;
    dbms_sql.close_cursor(cursor_v);
  end loop;
  if (urowid_t.count > 0) then
    return urowid_t(trunc(dbms_random.value(0, urowid_t.count)));
  end if;
  return null;
exception when others then
  if (dbms_sql.is_open(cursor_v)) then
    dbms_sql.close_cursor(cursor_v);
  end if;
  raise;
end;
/
show errors
```

Answer (score 1):

Below Solution to this question is not the exact answer but in many  scenarios you try to select a row and try to use it for some purpose and then update its status with "used" or "done" so that you do not select it again.

Solution:

Below query is useful but that way if your table is large, I just tried and see that you definitely face performance problem with this query.

SELECT * FROM
( SELECT * FROM table
ORDER BY dbms_random.value )
WHERE rownum = 1

So if you set a rownum like below then you can work around the performance problem. By incrementing rownum you can reduce the possiblities. But in this case you will always get rows from the same 1000 rows. If you get a row from 1000 and update its status with "USED", you will almost get different row everytime you query with "ACTIVE"

```
SELECT * FROM
( SELECT * FROM table
where rownum < 1000
  and status = 'ACTIVE'
  ORDER BY dbms_random.value  )
WHERE rownum = 1
```

update the rows status after selecting it, If you can not update that means another transaction has already used it. Then You should try to get a new row and update its status. By the way, getting the same row by two different transaction possibility is 0.001 since rownum is 1000.

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged in stackoverflow. Also, that Oracle code would be really slow on a large table.

Comment: just fixed did not know that

Answer (score 1):

Someone told sample(x) is the fastest way you can.
But for me this method works slightly faster than sample(x) method.
It should take fraction of the second (0.2 in my case) no matter what is the size of the table. If it takes longer try to use hints (--+ leading(e) use_nl(e t) rowid(t)) can help

```
SELECT *
  FROM My_User.My_Table
 WHERE ROWID = (SELECT MAX(t.ROWID) KEEP(DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY dbms_random.value)
                  FROM (SELECT o.Data_Object_Id,
                               e.Relative_Fno,
                               e.Block_Id + TRUNC(Dbms_Random.Value(0, e.Blocks)) AS Block_Id
                          FROM Dba_Extents e
                          JOIN Dba_Objects o ON o.Owner = e.Owner AND o.Object_Type = e.Segment_Type AND o.Object_Name = e.Segment_Name
                         WHERE e.Segment_Name = 'MY_TABLE'
                           AND(e.Segment_Type, e.Owner, e.Extent_Id) =
                              (SELECT MAX(e.Segment_Type) AS Segment_Type,
                                      MAX(e.Owner)        AS Owner,
                                      MAX(e.Extent_Id) KEEP(DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY Dbms_Random.Value) AS Extent_Id
                                 FROM Dba_Extents e
                                WHERE e.Segment_Name = 'MY_TABLE'
                                  AND e.Owner = 'MY_USER'
                                  AND e.Segment_Type = 'TABLE')) e
                  JOIN My_User.My_Table t
                    ON t.Rowid BETWEEN Dbms_Rowid.Rowid_Create(1, Data_Object_Id, Relative_Fno, Block_Id, 0)
                   AND Dbms_Rowid.Rowid_Create(1, Data_Object_Id, Relative_Fno, Block_Id, 32767))
```

Comment: Interesting approach.  But I can't get this to consistently run fast on my system.  And for small tables it often returns no rows.

Comment: I think speed is not consistent, because of Dba_Extents caching or sql parsing.

Comment: "for small tables it often returns no rows"

Comment: "for small tables it often returns no rows". It's because extent has minimum 64k. On my machine 8 data blocks. If table has few rows. All rows are in one block. So in this case probability to get random block with any records is 1/8. sample(x) returns no rows often if x is close 1/record_count. For small tables there is no point to worry max(rowid) keep(dense_rank first order by dms_random.value) works just fine.

Comment: If you have table statistics, you can get watermark and use it instead of Dba_Extens.Blocks to reduce "no rows returned" cases. Also extens have few blocks reserved by oracle. It is posible to avoid these blocks too

Comment: You can use recursive sql to retry if no rows are returned

Answer (score 0):

Version with retries when no rows returned:

```
WITH gen AS ((SELECT --+ inline leading(e) use_nl(e t) rowid(t)
                     MAX(t.ROWID) KEEP(DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY dbms_random.value) Row_Id
                FROM (SELECT o.Data_Object_Id,
                             e.Relative_Fno,
                             e.Block_Id + TRUNC(Dbms_Random.Value(0, e.Blocks)) AS Block_Id 
                        FROM Dba_Extents e
                        JOIN Dba_Objects o ON o.Owner = e.Owner AND o.Object_Type = e.Segment_Type AND o.Object_Name = e.Segment_Name
                       WHERE e.Segment_Name = 'MY_TABLE'
                         AND(e.Segment_Type, e.Owner, e.Extent_Id) =
                            (SELECT MAX(e.Segment_Type) AS Segment_Type,
                                    MAX(e.Owner)        AS Owner,
                                    MAX(e.Extent_Id) KEEP(DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY Dbms_Random.Value) AS Extent_Id
                               FROM Dba_Extents e
                              WHERE e.Segment_Name = 'MY_TABLE'
                                AND e.Owner = 'MY_USER'
                                AND e.Segment_Type = 'TABLE')) e
                JOIN MY_USER.MY_TABLE t ON t.ROWID BETWEEN Dbms_Rowid.Rowid_Create(1, Data_Object_Id, Relative_Fno, Block_Id, 0)
                                                  AND Dbms_Rowid.Rowid_Create(1, Data_Object_Id, Relative_Fno, Block_Id, 32767))),
  Retries(Cnt, Row_Id) AS (SELECT 1, gen.Row_Id
                             FROM Dual
                             LEFT JOIN gen ON 1=1
                            UNION ALL
                           SELECT Cnt + 1, gen.Row_Id
                             FROM Retries
                             LEFT JOIN gen ON 1=1
                            WHERE Retries.Row_Id IS NULL AND Retries.Cnt < 10)
SELECT *
  FROM MY_USER.MY_TABLE
 WHERE ROWID = (SELECT Row_Id
                  FROM Retries
                 WHERE Row_Id IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: You should probably delete this answer and add it to your other answer.  Also you may want to put the hint in the original answer.  And it might be worth noting that `SEGMENT_TYPE` will not always be 'TABLE', it could also be 'TABLE PARTITION' and probably some other values.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use pseudorandom rows?

```
select * from (
  select * from ... where... order by ora_hash(rowid)
) where rownum<100
```